# How to call a method with a parameter on tap of an image?

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that the selector method cannot include arguments, but now I'm at a loss as to how I should go about what I want to do.

My objective is to have 5 UI Image Views, each with an image of a star. When the image is tapped, the star should swap images to grey or blue.

My question is, how do I write only one method that handles changing the star image, depending on which star is tapped? Ideally, I would like to send the image as an argument to the method, though I know that is not possible. The only way I can see around this is to write a method for each of the five stars, but as the code would be identical, I feel like there must be a better way.

On View Did Load:

```
    // add tap recognition to rating stars
    let tapGestureRecognizerOne = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.changeStar))
    starOneEditImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    starOneEditImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerOne)
    let tapGestureRecognizerTwo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.changeStar))
    starTwoEditImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    starTwoEditImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerTwo)
    let tapGestureRecognizerThree = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.changeStar))
    starThreeEditImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    starThreeEditImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerThree)
    let tapGestureRecognizerFour = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.changeStar))
    starFourEditImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    starFourEditImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerFour)
    let tapGestureRecognizerFive = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.changeStar))
    starFiveEditImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    starFiveEditImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerFive)
```

And then a method to call on tap of the image:

```
 func changeStar() {

        print ("star tapped")

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the selector method cannot include arguments

You understand wrong. The parameter to `changeStar` is the gesture recognizer. And gesture recognizer has a `view`, and that's the image view you want!

```
func changeStar(g:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let v = g.view as! UIImageView
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! You answered so quickly that I can't accept the answer for another 9 mins, so I'll make sure to come back and do it.